# Android Realtime Multiplayer notify connection lost

Tags: android, google-play-games, multiplayer

I am using RealTime Multiplayer to create an Android game from here:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer

If two players are connected to a room, and the Internet Connection of one of them is interrupting, i want the other player to get notified.

Currently i don't see any listener that is called when a connection with other player has been lost.

Is there any way to manage this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you post your code? explain how you encountered the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @d.datul1990 I am implementing the interface RoomStatusUpdateListener that has the methods onPeersDisconnected() and onP2PDisconnected(), but none of these methods are called when a player has a broken connection. These methods are called only when a user manually exits the game (room), but are not called if the wireless/mobile data are turned off

Answer (score 3):

I have used `RealTimeMultiplayer.ReliableMessageSentCallback` interface implemented at the activity and have used workaround this in the following way

```
 @Override
        public void onRealTimeMessageSent(int statusCode, int tokenId, String recipientParticipantId) {
            switch (statusCode) {

                case GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK:
                    messageSent = true;
                    break;

                case GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_REAL_TIME_ROOM_NOT_JOINED:
                    break;

                case GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_REAL_TIME_MESSAGE_SEND_FAILED:
                    messageSent = false;
                    break;

            }
        }
```

but still the `GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_REAL_TIME_MESSAGE_SEND_FAILED` gets called after say 15 to 30 seconds later

Answer (score 2):

It is a workaround but you an try,

1. You can repeatedly send massages from both the players to ensure
   that the players are connected to network say every 1000
   milliseconds,
2. If you didn't get a message for say 2000 milliseconds then there
       might be an error at the other players end

Answer (score 0):

Create a listener and check network changes

```
// Indicates the state of Wi-Fi P2P connectivity has changed.
intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
```

Comment: Already using, look there is one on one match between 2 players ,say player 1 loses connection we can use your solution , but other player (Player 2) who has network connection needs to know if player 1 has lost connection